# How to set the path in opendir() in an included file?

Tags: php, directory, relative-path, absolute-path, opendir

In my application root folder I have a folder named 'articles' in which there are some files. And in my root folder I have the header file and some other files. The same header file is used in the files inside the articles directory too.

In my header file, I have a dropdown menu which lists the files inside the articles directory. And I have used the following code.

```
<?php
                $dir = "./articles";
                if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {

                    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

                        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && $entry != "images" && $entry != "index.php") {
                            $foo = $entry;
                            $foo = str_replace("_", " ", $foo);
                            $foo = str_replace(".php", "", $foo);
                            $foo = ucwords($foo);
                            ?>
                            <a class="dropdown-content-a" href="<?php echo "$entry" ?>"><?php echo $foo ?></a>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }

                    closedir($handle);
                }
                ?>
```

This works fine in the files in the root folder but it does not work in the files in the 'articles' folder(But the header file is still in the root folder and relative to the header file, the path './articles' is correct).

How to overcome this by using the same header file?

Comment: Have you tried defining a root directory and using that?

Comment: Is it by using define('APP_BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__)); in a config file?

Comment: `define('APP_BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).'/');`

Answer (score 2):

use (..) to cd the previous directory

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../filename.php');
```

Comment: doesn't that affect it when the header is used in the files of the root folder?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a condition-wise solution. Check the path and decide to use ".." or not.